# How to create an object of specific Java class from JSON object depending on it's fields values?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize objects from JSON file.
I have abstract class `Car`, which is extended by `Minibus` and `Minivan` classes.
I determine the exact class by values of `maxPassengers` and `trunkSize` fields.

I need to create a `MinibusCar` or `MinivanCar` object when I deserialize based on the parameters in JSON. What is the most efficient way to do that? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here. Can you show us an example of this json file?

In general, you can use Jackson package:

```
    // Serialize into JSONObject
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

    // Get your value from it, for example:
    int maxPassengers = json.get("maxPassengers");

    // Init your object mapper
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Based on this value, create your object
    Car car; // Using polymorphism (you can also read about Factory design pattern)
    if (maxPassengers > 10){
        car = mapper.readValue(jsonTxt, MinibusCar.class);
    } else {
        car = mapper.readValue(jsonTxt, MinivanCar.class);
    }
```

But this solution isn't perfect until you will show us the classes (three of them) and some json example file.

Good luck!